# Click “Accept Cookies” popup with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies

I've been trying to scrape some information of this E-commerce website with selenium. However when I access the website I need to accept cookies to continue. This only happens when the bot accesses the website, not when I do it manually. When I try to find the corresponding element either by xpath, as I find it when I inspect the page manually I always get this error message:

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

My code is mentined below.

```
import time
import pandas
pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #pip install beautifulsoup4

PATH = "/Users/Ziye/Desktop/Python/chromedriver"
delay = 15

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://en.zalando.de/women/?q=michael+michael+kors+taschen")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="uc-btn-accept-banner"]').click()
```

This is the HTML corresponding to the button "That's ok". The XPATH is as above.

```html
<button aria-label="" id="uc-btn-accept-banner" class="uc-btn uc-btn-primary">
                          That’s OK <span id="uc-optin-timer-display"></span>
                      </button>
```

Does anyone know where my mistake lies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add explicit wait for this button:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://en.zalando.de/women/?q=michael+michael+kors+taschen")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="uc-btn-accept-banner"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="uc-btn-accept-banner"]').click()
```

Your locator is correct.
As css selector, you can use `.uc-btn-footer-container .uc-btn.uc-btn-primary`